# Create Json Array of Excel file's Data In Node.js

Tags: node.js

When User Upload Excel File at that time i want to create json array of Excel      file's Data Using Node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xlsx-to-json:

```
var xlsx = require("xlsx-to-json");

xlsx({
    input: "aaaa.xlsx",
    output: null
  }, function(err, transcations) {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(transcations);
    }
  });
```